# Algolia -> Unable to make filters work with ais-configure Widget

Tags: angular, filter, algolia

I'm using Angular [ais-configure](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/configure/angular/) and attempting to add filters to searchParameters like this:

```
<ais-configure [searchParameters]="{ filters: 'isPrivate:false' }">
```

This is in order to filter on a boolean attribute

> isPrivate

in my documents.

However, the filter doesn't work. Actually, it filters all documents irrespective of the value of the attribute. I tried multiple variations, but no luck. And, when I remove the filters parameter, I get all my results back.

Here's my complete code

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="{indexName: 'xx_dummy_index', searchClient: algoliasearch('XXXXX', 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy')}">
  <ais-search-box [autofocus]="true" placeholder="Search for Questions...">
  </ais-search-box>
  <ais-stats></ais-stats>
  <ais-refinement-list attribute="tags"></ais-refinement-list>
  <ais-configure
    [searchParameters]="{ filters: 'isPrivate:false' }">
  </ais-configure>
  <ais-pagination [padding]="3" [showFirst]="true" [showLast]="true"
    [showPrevious]="true" [showNext]="true">
  </ais-pagination>
  <ais-hits>
    <ng-template let-hits="hits" let-results="results">
      <ol>
        <div *ngIf="hits.length === 0">
           No results found matching <strong>{{results.query}}</strong>.
        </div>
        <li *ngFor="let hit of hits" class="ais-Hits-item">
          <app-row [hit]="hit"></app-row>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </ng-template>
  </ais-hits>
</ais-instantsearch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Turns out that the right format for providing this input is as follows:

HTML File:

```
<ais-configure [searchParameters]="searchParameters"></ais-configure>
```

TyepScript File:

```
this.searchParameters = {
      hitsPerPage: 7,
      filters: 'isPrivate:false',
    };
```

Comment: Before using the given solution, one must configure the faceting in order to use the isPrivate variable as a search parameter. Checkout this link https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/solutions/ecommerce/business-users/initial-configuration/faceting/#step-1-declare-attributes-for-faceting